# Unity C#, How to addition X days to a date?

Tags: c#

In this part of code sDate show current date 2016/11/16, Now what is best way to add 7 days to current date? for example if current date is 2016/11/29 + 7 change to 2016/12/06. I'm looking for a way to addition an int value to a date.

```
string Year;
string Month;
string Day;
float time;
string sDate;

void Start () 
{

        Year = System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        Month = System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
        Day = System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();

        int Y = int.Parse (Year);
        int M = int.Parse (Month);
        int D = int.Parse (Day);


        if (Y >= 2016 & M >= 11 & D >= 21) 
        {
            sDate = Year + "/" + Month + "/" + Day + " | Expired";
            Debug.Log (sDate);

            Application.Quit ();
        } 
        else 
        {
            sDate = Year + "/" + Month + "/" + Day + " | Working";
            Debug.Log ("System date: " + sDate);
        }

}
```

Comment: Just use `DateTime.AddDays`.  Also why are you converting integers to strings and then parsing them back to integers?

Comment: I'm new to C# please write code example

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You might want to try learning how to do string date formatting, it will make your `sDate = Year + "/" + Month + "/" + Day + " | Expired";` a lot simpiler.

Comment: You can also compare date directly using the `DateTime` struct. ex: `if (DateTime.Today >= new DateTime(2016, 11, 21)) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Thanks a lot you helped me to reduce a lot of this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is use the standard DateTime function [`AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime result = original.AddDays(n);
```

where `original` is the original date and `n` is the number of days you want to add.

I'd also check the rest of the documentation on the `DateTime` structure as there are a lot simpler ways of doing what you are trying here. As mentioned in the comments you can construct a DateTime object from it's components:

```
DateTime referenceDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 15);
```

and then do comparisons on that:

```
if (testDate >= referenceDate)
{
    // Do something
}
```

etc.

Comment: You give a man a fish, you feed him for a day.  You give a man the link to MSDN, you feed him for life: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's hard to feed him for life if he isn't fully aware of how to eat.